# Check if third url paramter contain #value and get value

Tags: jquery

Check if third paramter contain #value. e.g `https://example.com/gallery/latest#2023`
Now I want to check that third parameter (latest#2023) having # and want to get value after # which is **2023**

Comment: `#` denotes a URL fragment and is not a valid URL character otherwise.

Comment: But it should be on 3rd place too

Comment: It doesn't matter in which "place" it is. Anything after `#` is part of the fragment. A URL of the form `url.com/one/two#whatever/three` doesn't mean "there is a path with three segments, which are `one`, `two#whatever`, and `three`". It only means "there are two segments `one` and `two`". It will only fetch the path `url.com/one/two` because `#whatever/three` is the fragment.

Comment: This MDN article may be worth reading: [MDN: Anatomy of a URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/Web_mechanics/What_is_a_URL#basics_anatomy_of_a_url)